# Joke's on you or Jokes on you

Tags: idioms, expressions, spoken-english

I hear that idiom quite often but honestly don't know if it's **"Joke is on you"** or **"Jokes on you"**. The pronunciation is basically the same, and it's mostly used in speech. So, is there a correct way or can I use both interchangeably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct idiom is: ***[Joke's on you](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+joke%27s+on)***.

> If you say that the joke is on a particular person, you mean that that person has tried to make someone else look silly but has made himself or herself look silly instead.

**Example**: Adam was laughing at John's poor sense of dressing, until John pointed out that Adam had forgotten to wear his pants. "*I guess the joke's on you now, Adam*" said John, who couldn't control his laughter.